# How to expand TeX's "main memory size"? (pgfplots memory overload)

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, tex-core, memory

I'm compiling one pretty simple LaTeX file with few dozen of `pgfplots`. Now, I can compile part by part, but am **unable to compile it all at once**. I really need good precision for all those plots (noise plots) and would like to avoid decimating graphs more. When I run compile, I get this error message:

```
[...] TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
```

**Is there a way to avoid this message somehow?** How am I supposed to use `pgfplots` if I can't plot couple dozen of figures with it without having TeX overloaded? **How to expand TeX memory size, please?**

Comment: One simple way of making tikz-figures created by `matlab2tikz` smaller is to use the command `cleanfigure` in Matlab, before using `matlab2tikz`.

I got this advice from a colleague recently.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package can be particularly heavy on TeX's memory, especially if you are creating plots with lots of data points. Indeed, there is a section in the `pgfplots` manual about expanding TeX's memory. However, that does not mean that expanding TeX's memory is the best solution. Instead, I would recommend using the 'externalization' approach (section 7.1 of the `pgfplots` manual).

The idea of externalization is to compile each plot as a separate TeX job. This leads to a graphic which can be used in the main job. Thus each plot has its own memory requirement, separate from all of the other plots. This usually avoids needing to make TeX's memory bigger. At the same time, the resulting files can be kept between TeX runs, which will speed up compilation for the second and subsequent runs. The latest version of the externalization system needs you to do two things. First, you put

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
```

in your preamble, to turn the system on. Secondly, you will need to enable 'shell escape'. This is done at the command line by adding the `-shell-escape` switch:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>
```

The same can be done in LaTeX editors: there is usually a place in the settings for this type of thing. I'll just add that shell escape does has some security implications: use only with documents that you trust!

Comment: I should probably say that I saw it coming. I had the feeling that "expanding the memory size" is not the answer, and **externalization** works flawlessly - plus, every following `pdflatex` run is ridiculously faster! Thanks! ...I should only find a way now to forward `-shell-escape` from `rubber --pdf` command that I'm using to `pdflatex`...

Comment: Also, try the `lualatex` compiler which appears to dynamically allocate more memory if it needs it.

Comment: Is there a more general solution that is not limited to pgf?

Comment: @joseph-wright, this is great, but now I change some of my pgfplots and they don't get updated automatically when compiling? It seems it's still using some old compiled figure. How do I force it to re-compile?

Comment: For everyone wondering why their images won't be updated after re-running `pdflatex` using the `-shell-escape` option: For every `tikzpicture` an extra `.pdf` file is created.
Either delete the file, so it will be recreated next time you run `pdflatex` or put a `\tikzset{external/force remake}` somewhere in your document.

Comment: I tried this, but i get an error: `! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "chap_naturalite-figure0" "\def\tikzextern
alrealjob{chap_naturalite}\input{chap_naturalite}"' did NOT result in a usable
output file 'chap_naturalite-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:).`.   Tried to delete the existing files and force remake but it does not change the problem.

Comment: @AlexandreWillame That is usually issued if you don't have shell escape enabled.

Comment: I have put the `-shell-escape` command for the build of pdflatex as you mentionned in your first post. My pdflatex command line is then written `pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. When I compile, some tables or figures are not in the correct place. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: it seems the first command should be `\usetikzlibrary{external}` (it only works then for me)

Comment: I got this error message: ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-eror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "wessex_journal_181012-figure0" "\def\tikz externalrealjob{wessex_journal_181012}\input{wessex_journal_18101}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'wessex_journal_181012-figure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed?

Comment: continued: Error messages can be found in 'wessex_journal_181012-figure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

Comment: Can that be related to admin rights on my work computer?

Comment: @JosephWright: I am very sorry for asking this, but where could I post your extension `pdflatex -shell-escape <filename>` in `TexStudio`? Probably in `Options` -> `Configure TexStudio` -> `PdfLaTeX`?

Comment: if you still have problems when externalised, you can increase the memory for the shelled process by adding `\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -extra-mem-top=10000000 -extra-mem-bot=10000000 -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}` (See Thomas F. Sturm's answer below for information about the -extra-mem flags.)

Answer (score 79):

Every now and then I have the same problem when compiling certain files. Of course, I have forgotten every time how I solved it in the past. Then, I google and I am getting to this page. Next, I remember that I landed on this page for several times, but, unfortunately, the answers did'nt help me in the past for my kind of problem. To break that Groundhog Day circle, I write down this answer which may help myself (for the next circle) and hopefully other people. The bad news is that it works only (?) for `MikTeX` users.

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000 --synctex=1 <filename>
```

You may replace `10000000` by another ridiculous high number.

As was commented by @coatless, you may have to add `--extra-mem-top=10000000` for other document types than my test example. The MiKTeX manual contains the following explanations:

- `--extra-mem-bot=n`: Set the extra size (in memory words) for large data structures like boxes, glue, breakpoints, et al. Relevant only after the memory dump file has been read.
- `--extra-mem-top=n`: Set the extra size (in memory words) for chars, tokens, et al. Relevant only after the memory dump file has been read.

For illustration some example log entries from a test document:

*Failing example without the extra memory:*

```
21229 strings out of 493921
360228 string characters out of 3152094
3000000 words of memory out of 3000000
24030 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
49729 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
```

*Working example with `--extra-mem-bot=10000000`:*

```
23652 strings out of 493921
401787 string characters out of 3152094
10571134 words of memory out of 13000000
24308 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
49729 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
```

*Working example with `--extra-mem-bot=100000000`:*

```
23652 strings out of 493921
401787 string characters out of 3152094
100571134 words of memory out of 103000000
24308 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
49729 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
```

I guess that my example in truth needed `571134` words of memory (and the the rest is eaten up for fun).

Comment: I had to use `--extra-mem-top=10000000` instead of `--extra-mem-bot=100000000` on MikTex x64 (Win 10) as the previous one didn't work well.

Comment: Many thanks @Coatless, I had the same issue, only worked with `--extra-mem-bot`

Comment: @Coatless Thanks. The `--extra-mem-top` solved it for me.

Comment: You can also set these permanently. Check Leo Liu's answer and change in that file the values for  `extra_mem_bot` and `extra_mem_top`.

Comment: Working solution for me as a MikTeX user. I wish I had come to it earlier. It would have spared me a lot of time spent at debugging attempts on a long document I'm developing.

Comment: Sorry for my stupid question, but where do I type this? I am running Windows 7, Miktex 2.9 and Texmaker 4.5.

Comment: @MrYouMath into cmd

Comment: but there is still limit to this `extra_mem` number, right?

Answer (score 60):

Due to AlexG's comment, the memory size has been a constant large value for recent versions of TeX Live. It seems you don't need to extend this.

In older TeX Live, you can modify `/some/path/to/texlive/some/subpath/web2c/texmf.cnf`, which can be found by typing on the terminal:

```
kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf
```

Then modify the memory size by including, e.g. :

```
main_memory = 3000000
```

(See comments in `texmf.cnf` file for more details.)

Then run the following command as root to recreate the format files:

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

Comment: @Edin: your correction is wrong. The file mentioned by Leo Liu is the one to modify, as it's not touched by any TeX Live update.

Comment: Thanks @egrep. In general things like that should not be modified directly but pointed out in a comment.

Comment: The `/some/path/to/texlive/2010/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` is the official config file which will be overwritten in an update. It should not be modified. Instead the `/some/path/to/texlive/2010/texmf.cnf` should be used to change all settings which are different from the default. This is pointed out in the comments of the main `web2c/texmf.cnf` config file, which maybe is what Leo Lio meant in his last sentence.

Comment: You can also set higher values for `extra_mem_bot` and `extra_mem_top`, which will give you even more memory in total. Also the description is saying that the maximum value for `main_memory` is 7999999.

Comment: @LeoLiu : The maximum value `main_memory = 12435455`(to be found by bisection) has been a constant for many TL releases now. I think it is worth noting in the answer.

Comment: This worked for me amazingly well, except it took me a while to find a place where to put it: TeXMaker/Options/Configure Texmaker/Commands. Also had the problem to specify `<filename>` so now every compilation of files that need the extra memory I get `!Latex Error: File 'MyTextfile.txt' not found`, but the pdf file is generated correctly. When compiling other, smaller, projects, no error occurs. The interaction between Texmaker and MikTeX has me totally confused. I would have assumed Texmaker Commands settings are across the board, not for specific .tex files.

Comment: That's the kind of solution I like: Just change a system parameter and not the toolchain or the document itself. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 39):

after trying all the options (changing texmf.cnf file, etc.) I found on the web, the only one that worked for me was to **use lualatex**. This is the simplest and more elegant way to do it. Lualatex is available in the Texlive distribution by default.

Comment: see http://macosx-tex.576846.n2.nabble.com/Lua-td6030741.html for instructions on using lualatex on a mac ::: note: in `pdfLuaLatex.engine` you may need to change `pdflualatex  -synctex=1 "$1"` to `lualatex  -synctex=1 "$1"`

Answer (score 13):

In MikTex, the memory size can be permanently increased by this way:

1, For **Windows**, Open a command Window and enter:

```
initexmf --edit-config-file=latex
```

For **Ubuntu**, try this:

```
gedit .miktex/texmfs/config/miktex/config/latex.ini
```

2. In the file opened (it may be empty), add:

   main_memory=12000000
3. Save the file and quit. Then in the command window, enter:

   initexmf --dump=latex

Then repeat the above steps for pdflatex (replace `latex` with `pdflatex`). If the error persists, try increasing the `main_memory` value. For lualatex, the memory allocation is dynamic, hence the aforementioned steps are unnecessary, but if the compilation fails for lualatex, try for that as well.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to this if anyone still has this problem, I found a pretty simple way to fix it. I was getting this error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]
```

**I went through a lot of guides to increase the main memory and nothing was working :/**

But I read a few articles where they talked about `save_size` instead of `main_memory`.

I edited my `texmf.cnf` but not the one in the `web2c` folder, I changed the at in the `..../texlive/yyyy/texmf.cnf` (since I'm using Windows my path was `C:\texlive\2015\texmf.cnf`). The file looked as follows:

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
OSFONTDIR = $SystemRoot/fonts//
```

So I added the following two lines:

```
main_memory = 7999999
save_size  = 7999999
```

I then opened up command prompt and ran:

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```

And that was it :) I was able to build my stuff! **I know that `save_size` wasn't mentioned at all in the error message but I found that adding that line fixed the issue** :)!

Answer (score 6):

It wasn't working for me either (MikTex on Win10 x64). I tried to change the pdflatex.ini file ([see here point 4](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/wiki/TeX-capacity-exceeded,-sorry)) but ended with the error after the dump:

```
Sorry, but "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-pdftex.exe" did not succeed.
```

Therefore I did following: MikeTex Settings -> Formats, looked for pdflatex and clicked "Build". Again an error, but then I opened the pdflatex.ini, changed line for line the maximum value and looked up to which it still was able to succesful "Build".

Now it works with these values (8GB RAM):

```
main_memory=79999999 
save_size=79999
extra_mem_bot=79999999 
extra_mem_top=79999999 
font_mem_size=799999
pool_size=7999999
buf_size=7999999
EnableWrite18=p
stack-size=200000
max-strings=79999999
```

Comment: So, that is the largest? How to set for `XeLaTeX`?

Answer (score 1):

By writing my document I also got this error. I found a nice workaround without using LuaLaTeX, changing any properties or making somehow a picture of your desired diagram. You can still using pdfLaTeX.

The following steps describe how you have to proceed:

## (1)

As usual, create your *.tex-file with `matlab2tikz`.

## (2)

Create a minimal working example (MWE) like the one. The example has some additional packages with the [standalone](https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone) class too remove unneeded margin:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
%I don't know, why I have to include the preview as an optional argument. Without I got an error.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \input{< your generated *.tex-file >}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

## (3)

With step (2) you can now include the generated *.pdf-file in your "normal" document:

```
...
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics{< your generated *.pdf-file from step (2) >}
\caption[short text]{longer text}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
...
```

As you can see the advantages of this methode is that you can also include `captions` and `labels`.

Comment: Can you further explain how this help with capacity issues?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `\clearpage` command, it worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  It's possible that splitting up the processing of plots could decrease the need for more memory, but it might also result in making it impossible to place a;; plots where they are wanted.  More details, please.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TeXstudio go to **Options** > **Configure TeXstudio**, and on the **Build** tab change the **Default Compiler** from *PdfLaTex* to *LuaLaTeX*.

This solved my problem, I hope it can help somebody out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble to find how to increase the memory in a container of github action like mattnotmitt/doxygen-action, so saving for the future, in Doxyfile put this line:

```
LATEX_CMD_NAME = "\"pdflatex\" -cnf-line=extra_mem_top=12000000 -cnf-line=extra_mem_bot=12000000 -cnf-line=main_memory=12000000"
```