# Error when using surf in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to make a contour plot with pgfplots similar to the [`pyplot.contourf`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contourf) but I'm getting errors:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}    

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.dat}
  9.000000000000000000e+02 3.000000000000000000e+01 2.808099937438964844e+01
  9.000000000000000000e+02 3.500000000000000000e+01 2.836700057983398438e+01
  9.000000000000000000e+02 4.000000000000000000e+01 2.881599998474121094e+01
  1.000000000000000000e+03 3.000000000000000000e+01 2.826700019836425781e+01
  1.000000000000000000e+03 3.500000000000000000e+01 2.820400047302246094e+01
  1.000000000000000000e+03 4.000000000000000000e+01 2.856699943542480469e+01
  1.100000000000000000e+03 3.000000000000000000e+01 2.783799934387207031e+01
  1.100000000000000000e+03 3.500000000000000000e+01 2.806399917602539062e+01
  1.100000000000000000e+03 4.000000000000000000e+01 2.830699920654296875e+01
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{testdata.dat}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=10cm,
  height=5cm,
  small,
  colorbar
]
  \addplot3[surf,shader=interp] table{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The following error does appear when I'm using `shader=interp`:

```
! LuaTeX error /usr/share/texmf-  dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/lua/pgfplots.lua:27: attempt to call global 'unpack' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
  /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/lua/pgfplots.lua:27: in function 'pgfplotsGetLuaBinaryStringFromCharIndices'
  [string "\directlua "]:1: in main chunk.
  \pgfplotsbinarytoluabinary ...CharIndices({#1}); }
```

Comment: what version of `pgfplots` do you have? And you are compiling with `LuaLaTeX` right?

Comment: @Red I'm using lualatex and pgfplots v1.13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LuaTeX made an incompatible change in version 0.76 .

I added a version switch in `pgfplots` 1.9 which allows `pgfplots` to speak the two different, incompatible languages of luatex post 0.76 and pre 0.76.

Thus, the solution is to upgrade pgfplots to version 1.9 or to downgrade lualatex.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug/incompatibility fixed from version `1.6`/`1.6.1`:

> 1.6.1:
>
> - **fixed incompatibility lualatex,shader=interp**, and german package (introduced in 1.6)
>
> 1.6:
>
> - added support for layered graphics (main use case: multiple axes and layers)
> - added support for second colormap in mesh plots (mesh/interior colormap name)
> - added support for scopes inside of axes
> - contour plots: added ability to provide list of discrete labels (mesh/levels)
> - empty lines are interpreted as interruptions in data plots (was undocumented since 1.4)
> - added more scaling options to 'scale mode=scale uniformly' (affects axis equal in 3d   and \addplot3 graphics)
> - fixed wrong implementation of 'axis equal' and 'unit vector ratio' in 3d   (backwards compatible for 2d, but not for 3d - the 3d
>     implementation was plain wrong)
> - **fixed incompatibility of lualatex and shader=interp**
> - fixed bugs/added features around \addplot3 graphics
> - fixed bug: colorbar did not support ymode=log
> - fixed a couple of minor bugs
> - fixed bounding box computation for clip=false,axis lines=none

either update your version or compile with `pdflatex` (I'm not sure that this last option works)

Comment: But I'm using the latest version of pgfplots. Has this something to do with lualatex?

Comment: @Reza You said you have the version `1.3`, the latest version of `pgfplots` is the `1.9`...

Comment: I'm sorry this was a typo. My version is 1.9.

Comment: @Reza very strange... are you totally sure of having `pgfplots 1.9`? Search for this line in your `.log` file: `Package: pgfplots 2013/10/03 v1.9 Data Visualization (1.9)`. What version of LuaLaTeX do you have? (you can find it in the first line of the `.log` file)

Comment: Sorry was wrong, my version of pgfplots is v1.8, luatex is: `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013102717 (rev 4627)  (format=lualatex 2013.9.18)`

Comment: I don't know then... I have `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012062323` and `pgfplots 1.9` and it works... maybe @Christian Feuersänger knows the answer