# Large datafile for pgfplots table gives out of memory

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, externalize

I have a problem with 3D plots (surf, contours, ...) when loading "large" tables of data. I get the error `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].`.

I found an aswer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload), in particular to use `pdflatex --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000 --synctex=1 <filename>` (since I'm a MikTeX user), but it doesn't work at all and I simply get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=13000000].`.

Maybe it's important that I use TeXnicCenter, so I simply put `--extra-mem-bot=10000000` in the proper option as you can see [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17093893/texniccenter.JPG) (`-synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%Wm" -synctex=1 -shell-escape --extra-mem-bot=10000000`), but I always get memory errors. To give maximum info, I uploaded [the log file too](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17093893/provvisorio.log).

The MWE is the following (I apologize if it includes more packages than necessary, but now I'm in total panic). As you can see I try to externalize, but it doesn't work anyway.

If more information is needed for you to help me, please, let me know.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,patterns,shapes.arrows}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots,colormaps}
\usepackage[font=small,
            format=hang,
            labelfont={sf,bf},
            tableposition=top,
            figureposition=bottom]{caption}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[mesh]
         % the following works (it's 31x31 grid)
         %\addplot3[mesh/rows=31,mesh/cols=31,mesh/ordering=colwise,shader=interp] table[x=X,y=Y,z=psi] {immagini/data/SPIKE_30x30_Re1000_it10000_psi.dat};
         % whereas the following doesn't, for being 101x101
         \addplot3[mesh/rows=101,mesh/cols=101,mesh/ordering=colwise,shader=interp] table[x=X,y=Y,z=psi] {immagini/data/SPIKE_100x100_Re1000_it10000_psi.dat};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Stream lines and contours of pressure.}
    \label{fig:SPIKE_30x30_Re1000_it10000_p_psi}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

The datafile is downloadable [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17093893/SPIKE_100x100_Re1000_it10000_psi.dat)

**EDIT**: I encountered the same problem with the TeXLive distribution on a Mac OS X (using TeXShop as editor). [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286454/tex-capacity-exceeded-using-pgfplots-with-without-externalization) is the question I posted, along with my self-answer, which can be an answer to the present question too (to use LuaLaTeX).

Comment: It compiled for me with `--extra-mem-top=10000000` (I didn't use the externalization, if you use it you will have to add the option to the program call used by the externalization code, see the documentation.).

Comment: Ops.. In the answer I referenced there is an error: `--extra-mem-bot=10000000` instead of `--extra-mem-top=10000000`. I changed to `top` and now the problem is fixed

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Could you please add this as an answer so that this question is no longer unanswered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It compiled for me with `--extra-mem-top=10000000` (I didn't use the externalization, if you use it you will have to add the option to the program call used by the externalization code, see the documentation.).

Comment: Would it be useful to write explicitly that my error was to write `bot` instead of `top`?

Comment: Well the error was not to check the documentation. Then you would have seen that there are two options for "main memory" and got the idea to try out the other one. http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pdftex.html.