# Huge pstricks graph max memory exceeded

Tags: pstricks, memory

i have to update a very old reporting system wich uses latex, dvips and gs to generate pdf reports.

On the old server, the following is installed:

```
pdftex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
kpathsea version 5.0.0
Copyright 2009 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.44; using libpng 1.2.44
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3.4; using zlib 1.2.3.4
Compiled with poppler version 0.12.4
```

on the new system:

```
pdftex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.28; using libpng 1.6.28
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.48.0
```

everything is working fine, except a whole year report with tons of datapoints.

i checked the .tex file on the old server, it's compiling fine.
on the new one i run out of memory

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=17000000]
```

I know about all the other posts, recommendung reducing the number of datapoints ect... that's unfortunately no option at this moment.

the source can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jm3hyir9qc4t6jv/long_graph.tex?dl=0

thanks for your time!

Comment: Please include your code in this site as a MWE. Because, external links will be dead over-time.

Comment: Might be interesting: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload

Comment: How much memory is the compilation using on the old system? (It should be at the end of the log-file).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4426 strings out of 493912
 58759 string characters out of 1155296
 3418949 words of memory out of 20000000
 7605 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 8690 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 706 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,11n,52p,857b,272s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Comment: I already tried to increase the memory any further but get the error message "my internal constants have been clobbered"

Comment: `20,000,000 ` is a lot. That looks as if you extended the memory locally. But your document used only `3,418,949` and it is not quite clear why it should suddenly need `17,000,000`.

Answer (score 2):

The example looks like an export from a graphic program and it is more or less rubbish. For example: a lot of `\psline[linecolor=orange,...](..,...)(...,...)` are showing a continues plot. It's absolutely senseless to use single `\psline` macros where the last coordinates are the first of the next `\psline`. This is the same for SIX lines in your code:

```
\psline[linewidth=0.5pt, linecolor=orange] 
       (0.0,70.875)(0.044398907104,69.75)(0.088797814207,68.875)(0.133196721312,68.75)(0.177595628415,68.375)
       (0.221994535518,68.75)(0.266393442624,72.125)
```

However: Use a scripting language and extract the coordinates of all lines with the same color and then use a simple `\fileplot` or `\listplot`