# TeX capacity exceeded: How to increase main memory size of TeX Live on a Debian machine?

Tags: texlive, size, memory, debian, maintenance

When trying to compile a huge `pgfplot` with several plots I receive the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]. \end{document}
```

There is no error in code as compiling goes completely fine when not compiling all plots in once.

---

To increase the mentioned `main memory size` on a Debian machine I found [this](https://gordonlesti.com/debian-increase-latex-main-memory-size/) solution:

1. Edit `/etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf` and add these values:

   ```
   main_memory = 12000000
   extra_mem_bot = 12000000
   font_mem_size = 12000000
   pool_size = 12000000
   buf_size = 12000000
   ```
2. Run `update-texmf`
3. Run `texhash`

---

Unfortunately, executing `update-texmf` delivers a `command not found`. Is there some other solution available to update/increase the `main memory`? However, the second command `texhash` went fine (but is useless without succeeding the first one I guess?).

Comment: What is reported by 1) `ls -l /usr/sbin/update-texmf` [Is the file really missing?] 2) `dpkg -l tex-common`  [Have you installed package providing the file?]

Comment: According to the page given both should have been sudo so it should have said `sudo update-texmf` first then `sudo texhash` and you can try bumping up to12500000 but drop some of the others such as fonts I seem to remember its not a good idea to keep them inflated (hmm must check mine later) also review https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload

Comment: AnFi  identified that /usr/sbin/update-texmf should have been installed by tex-common which also included the file /etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf so beware dpkg may overwrite so take a backup of your .cnf edits

Comment: @AnFi: According to 1), requesting `ls -l /usr/sbin/update-texmf` delivers a `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2659 Feb 28 15:28 /usr/sbin/update-texmf`, so the file seems not to be missing. According to 2), executing `dpkg -l tex-common` brings `ii  tex-common  6.11  all  common infrastructure for building and installing TeX`, and furthermore `dpkg -s tex-common` brings `Status: install ok installed`. I guess everything should be fine here, no?

Comment: If the command is valid (not corrupt) then it should work if that location is correctly configured for shell (so importantly may need to check that out)  OR you could run from that location (navigate there to run) but that should not be the way to go.

Comment: use: `sudo -i` and then `update-texmf`