# TeX capacity exceeded: Is available main memory size depending on machines RAM?

Tags: texlive, compiling, size, memory, performance

I had the case that I ran into `TeX capacity exceeded` several times when compiling a `pgfplot` with lots of data points on a machine with 4096 MB RAM.

Now I've tried to compile the very same file on a machine with 20 GB RAM and it worked completely flawless.

Is TeX Lives `main memory size` dependent of machines RAM, or is it just a software depending value?

Comment: AFAIK it's a software-defined value, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953 for example.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: Thanks a lot - that's pretty interesting! What else could be the reason that it worked on a second machine without complaining about the memory size?

Comment: I do not know, maybe there is a command line option that shows the settings on each system and you can compare the results. I would look for "Tex Live Memory Settings", I found a German site that looks promising (https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/texlive-memory-vergroessern/).

Comment: Does the compilation need the same memory on both systems?

Comment: show the end of the log for the two cases, in particular that will show the memory settings of the two installations, eg a successful run will say something like `95365 words of memory out of 5000000`

Comment: The original TeX ran on batch machines with memory/class limits.  Initex created a memory image after running all the standard macro definitions.  This image was executable, but only using the memory it was created with (see also bigtex).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks a lot for this hint! On the "weak" machine: `5000000 words of memory out of 5000000` while on the "strong" machine:  `4949357 words of memory out of 5000000`. Why does the strong machine consume less memory for the exactly same file?

Comment: @Dave ooh so you only just scraped home on the successful run:-)  If you add `\listfiles` and compare package versions then some package or other will be different and using a bit more memory and tip you over the limit. In any case you sould be able to increase main mem in`texmf.cnf`