# Error with \usepackage{pgfplots}

Tags: pgfplots

everybody.

I am trying to use pgfplots package. I got it from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/ and saved in the same directory of the source file. I declared the package writing:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat-1.16}.
```

When running the source file, I get the following error message:
'I can't find file `pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex'. \input pgfplotsoldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex'.

How could I overcome this problem?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Giuseppe

Comment: Well… why didn't you install it with your package manager?

Comment: MikTeX says it has already been installed. But it doesn't run.

Comment: What do you mean with ‘it doesn't run’?

Comment: Do you refresh file name data base?

Comment: @Bernard, it crashes. Compilation never gets to an end (with or without errors) and I can't see my pdf.

Comment: @Zarko, i. e. installing new updates?

Comment: if you install package by help of MikTeX Console, it automatically refresh FNDB ( file name data base). If you do manually without use of console, than you need refresh FNBD (with use of console/Task). why you not use package available on CTAN? it can be that version on `sourceforge` is not stable.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to install a package manually. Usually it is *much* better to let your TeX distribution handle those sort of things. `pgfplots` depends on `pgf` (Ti*k*Z) and so you should always update these two packages together. If you install and update packages through the MikTeX Console this should be very easy. Manual updates have all sort of pitfalls and make it tedious to update all packages involved. Make sure to update MikTeX at leas twice in User and Admin mode. Then make sure that `pgfplots` is installed.

Comment: Thanks, everybody. I finally followed moewe's suggestion and installed the package with MikTex: now the compilation ends successfully. The only problem is now that the compilation lasts one minute and a half, before showing the complete pdf file. Any suggestion to make it speedier?

Comment: That's a completely different question, so might be better to actually post a new question. That said, you can consider using fewer samples (if you're plotting functions), or externalizing the plot (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload/7965#7965, it answers a different question, but briefly describes externalization).