# Matlab2tikz - TeX Capacity Exceeded - Trying to Run `lualatex` Command

Tags: luatex, mactex, macos

I have been creating vector graphics with the matlab2tikz tool and got the error message `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000]`. As I found out on the [matlab2tikz github page](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/wiki/TeX-capacity-exceeded,-sorry) page I might be able to resolve the issue by running the `lualatex` command to remove the strict memory limitation. It is suggested to type into the system prompt:

`lualatex main.tex`

I am using a mac and therefore type this into the `Terminal`.

I get the following response:

[image]

MY QUESTION IS: What do I need to do to successfully run the command?

Comment: Is `main.tex` in your home directory? You need to navigate into the folder containing `main.tex` with `cd`. You can check if your are in the correct directory by typing `ls` in the command line. If  `main.tex` is listed in the output of `ls` you are in the right place.

Comment: Just to be clear, the main.tex should be my preamble LaTeX file, correct? If I go the the folder which contains the preamble document using `cd ~/Documents/Studium/Masterstudium\ Medizintechnik/Masterarbeit/Ausarbeitung` and try to use `ls` I get `ls: .: Operation not permitted`. :(
Trying to use `lualatex Ausarbeitung.tex`, where Ausarbeitung.tex is my main.tex filename I get `! I can't find file Ausarbeitung.tex.`

Comment: No `main.tex` needs to be your main document file. Usually that is the file starting with `\documentclass`, but depending on your setup (if you have an externalised preamble that also externalises the document class) it may start differently. If `main.tex` contains *only* your preamble code, it is quite probably not the right file to compile. I don't know anything about Macs, but I always thought there were Unixoid and `ls` should work... (maybe this explains the `ls` thingy? https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/339862)

Comment: What Editor or Front End are you using? Did you typeset from within your editor before?

Comment: @moewe this helped a great bit! I was able to use the `ls` command and run the lualatex on my `main.tex` file. It ran through with me pressing `enter` at each `?` popping up. I hope this was the right thing to do. 
While my LaTeX file does run through with this specific vector graphic not included it sill crashes with `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].` if it's included. Did I do something wrong or does this just not work for me?
One vector graphic with 2KB works but this with 32KB does not. `Jpeg`s with 900+KB work fine though. How can this be?

Comment: @HerbSchulz I am using `Texmaker`. I unfortunately don't know what a `Front End` is and neither what you mean by typesetting.

Comment: Mhhh, normally you only get `?` prompts when there is an error. In that case you should investigate why that error appears, fix it and re-run LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe I got rid of all my errors and reran LuaLaTeX. I am still getting the exact same error message. What would you suggest to do now? I am trying to use the clean `cleanfigure()` command of `matlab2tikz` now.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I thought that LuaTeX does dynamic allocation, so I would not have expected the error. Maybe you want to think about externalising your figures. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7953/35864

Comment: Thank you for your help though. I will describe below that using the `cleanfigure` command was a workaround for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LuaTeX` did not work for me, even after I deleted all of my `Errors`, which showed up in my log-file.

However the `cleanfigure` command suggested under "2." [on the GitHub Page](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz/wiki/TeX-capacity-exceeded,-sorry) did the job for me. This is a snippet of the Matlab code I use now:

```
cleanfigure
matlab2tikz('/Users/timonschulz/Documents/Studium/Masterstudium Medizintechnik/Masterarbeit/Ausarbeitung/Figures/Ergebnisse/MS1_P3_standardisiert_mg_pro_mW.tikz')
```