# capacity exceeded error when using l-system

Tags: tikz-pgf, lindenmayer

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Tree}{
  \rule{F -> F [ R [+F] [-F] ]}
  \symbol{R}{
    \pgflsystemstep=0.6\pgflsystemstep
  } 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw l-system [l-system={Tree, axiom=[F], step=20, order=9, angle=60}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It worked earlier this year, but now when I try to use it, it says

```
Runaway definition?
->\pgfsyssoftpath@movetotoken {0.0pt}{0.0pt}\pgfsyssoftpath@linetotoken \ETC.
./lindmanyer.tex:12: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\pgfsyssoftpath@thepath ...oken {23.264pt}{22\ETC.
>                                                  
> l.12 ...], step=20, order=9, angle=60}] l-system ;
```

I have no idea what causes it and how to fix it.

Comment: I tried the code with TeX Live from 2016 to 2023 and the error is always the same. The library for Lindenmayer systems has basically not changed since 2019.

Comment: With `\pgflsystemstep=0.6\pgflsystemstep` the library needs an exhaustive amount of main memory. However the example works without error, if you'd use LuaLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: pdftex and xetex use fixed memory sizes. However, you can increase these limits in the config file and then rebuild the formats. This has been answered multiple times here already, e.g., here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload.   Luatex allocates its memory dynamically, so there is no need to edit the config files if you use luattex.

Comment: With `F -> F [R+F] [R-F]` and `axiom = F` (no need for a group here) you can get PDFLaTeX to do `order = 9` but not 10 anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example requires an extremely large amount of main memory with PDFLaTeX — more than is usually statically allocated for it. I would therefore recommend compiling the example with LuaLaTeX, which dynamically allocates the required memory.

If in real life the example is an image in a larger document which cannot be converted to LuaLaTeX quickly, try to compile only the `tikzpicture` environments or alternatively only this one via `external` library with LuaLaTeX. However, for this it is necessary to activate shell-escape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
  -halt-on-error -interachtion=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}]

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Tree}{
  \rule{F -> F [ R [+F] [-F] ]}
  \symbol{R}{
    \pgflsystemstep=0.6\pgflsystemstep
  } 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw l-system [l-system={Tree, axiom=[F], step=20, order=9, angle=60}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: Depending on packages you are using, this could fail, e.g., if you are loading a package, that should not be used with `lualatex`. In this case, it can help to load packages depending by engine, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[system call={lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape
  -halt-on-error -interachtion=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}]

\pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Tree}{
  \rule{F -> F [ R [+F] [-F] ]}
  \symbol{R}{
    \pgflsystemstep=0.6\pgflsystemstep
  } 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw l-system [l-system={Tree, axiom=[F], step=20, order=9, angle=60}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As an alternative that does neither need shell-escape nor a change of your document, you can increase the memory allocated for main memory with PDFLaTeX. With MiKTeX you can run

```
pdflatex --extra_mem_top=1000000 foo.tex
```

(if `foo.tex` is the name of your document). With TeX Live you can use, e.g.:

```
pdflatex -cnf-line="extra_mem_top=700000" foo.tex
```

The result is the same as shown above.

Comment: Thanks! This works.