Create 3D surface and color it with a 4th dimension
I am trying to make a 3D surface in pgfplots, and color it with data from a .csv file.
My file contains four columns. The first three correspond to the cartesian positions (x,y,z), and the fourth contains values that I would like to use for coloring the surface.
The problem is similar to this one, except that in their case, the 4th dimension is a function of the first 3. Similar situation
Making the surface is straightforward, but I cannot choose the fourth dimension.
Please help.
Here is my data: Data
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
   
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=12.5cm,
    margin=0.5cm,
    ]{geometry}


\begin{document}

% Preamble:
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18,label style={font=\huge}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
    \addplot3 [surf, mesh/rows=10, shader=interp]
        table[x=x, y=y, z=color, col sep=comma]{iso.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}


pgfplots may be a better tag than tikz-3dplot for this particular question, since it asks how to achieve this in pgfplots. That being said, I think tikz-3dplot offers more capabilities for editing. For instance, pgfplots makes surfaces with squares, when it would be better to make them with triangles, because three points are always coplannar, whereas four points often aren't. You would also be able to manually add the colours with a loop.

Thanks for the reply Jaster. I have added the tag and also I found a solution (reported below).

I found the solution. (Paraphrasing the manual) pfgplots uses "meta data" as attributes to each point. The default is to use the last spatial coordinate i.e., in a 3D surface plot, it uses "z", hence the color is related to that value. However, one can directly access this data (See  section 4.8.2)
The solution to the problem stated above is the following: Add the key words "point meta=explicit" in the axis options, and provide the metadata from the file as meta="column name", in this case "column name"=color.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
    
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=12.5cm,
    margin=0.5cm,
    ]{geometry}
    
\begin{document}

% Preamble:
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18,label style={font=\huge}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar, point meta=explicit]
    \addplot3 [surf, mesh/rows=10, shader=interp]
        table[x=x, y=y, z=z, meta=color, col sep=comma]{iso.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}

The resulting Fig. in my case is the following:


I believe you can accept your own answer. For the benefit of others, maybe add an image showing an interesting result.

Thanks for providing the reference! I use pgfplots quite a bit.

Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the final result. When making this "production" quality figure, I faced a problem of memory overload " TeX capacity exceeded". (The attached plot is made with (600x300 columnsXrows). I found the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload. I changed the builder to lualatex.
